# How do I create a custom form which auto generates cases and workflows?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm quite new to SalesForce development and am really struggling to work out how to do this.

Essentially I would like to build a custom form within Salesforce that allows me to select a Contact and then create a new case.set of tasks based on which checkboxes in the form are clicked.

For example, if I need a new computer and phone for John, I would open the form, enter John, tick the Computer and Phone checkboxes, and SalesForce would automatically create tasks under John's contact.

Is what I am proposing feasible within SalesForce? Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is: yes. The long one is... Well... Long. If you ask for something more detailed I'm sure you'll get better help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this... Process Builder, Flow, or Apex.  In all of them you'd have to add in check for each of the fields and then to create the Task based on that.

I would personally use Flow since I'm most comfortable with it, but if you're able to do it in Apex thats great too.  Process Builder would be less flexible to maintain in my opinion.

In the Flow you'd want to use a Fast Create to add all of the Tasks, so that its bulkified for a high volume of Tasks.  Essentially you'd check to see if the boxes are TRUE or not, if they are, then you go set the task and the criteria for it, add it to the collection of your 'tasks to create' and then proceed to find if the next field is TRUE or not for all of your fields.  Go through all of them, and then do your Fast Create of all of the tasks you need to create, and you can create the Case as well in a Record Create.  Shouldn't be too bad!